# Customize flutter app in android studio: open android flutter code

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have made an app in flutter. I want to add features to it (like ironsoure ad mediation) to it which has no flutter package at the moment. Can I add such features directly in android studio by opening the Android code that is generated by flutter? How can I do it?

Comment: Yes, you can directly open the `android/` directory in Android studio or add it as an additional module to your Flutter project, then you don't have to switch.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Where can I edit the code in the android directory? I searched directory but didn't find the code or logic that i wrote in flutter, in android http://icecream.me/056334211c2d52e35091d3adfd1a6249

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Flutter/Dart code is not converted to Android code, it's converted to machine code. What you are probably looking for is how to develop plugin packages (you can do the same directly in your application without creating an extra plugin package) https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#developing-plugin-packages

Answer (score 0):

You should write platform specific `MethodChannel` and implement using dart code.

Follow this link,
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels